# save is deprecated for what in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, deprecation-warning

I am reading documents from MongoDB collections with pymongo, then modify them, then save them back with [save](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/).

Unfortunately I started to receive deprecation warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: save is deprecated. Use insert_one or replace_one instead
```

The recommended replacements have different functionality: `insert_one` complains on duplicate `_id` and `update_one` requires filter parameter.

How to disable deprecation warning?

Comment: FYI, *"read -> modify -> save"* is the worst pattern ever, hence the education lesson in removing the function from the driver. What you are essentially doing is *"walking to the library and checking out a book, walking home then sitting at a desk, adding a new page in the book, then finally walking back to the library and putting the book on the shelf"*. The opposed actions in `update_one` or `replace_one` are essentially, *"send a new page to the librarian asking them to add it to nominated book"*. So you really should learn the distinction between the patterns.

Comment: I disagree on existing of "bad" or "good" patterns. Even I disagree on existence of patterns at all.

Answer (score 3):

if the document you want to save already has _id use [replace_one](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one) else use [insert_one](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one)

```
if '_id' in doc:    
    collection.replace_one({'_id': doc['_id']}, doc)
else:
    collection.insert_one(doc)
```

[save](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.save) will not be supported in the future versions of pymongo, it's better to stop using it.

Comment: What if there is no document with given `_id` in collection yet? `upsert` parameter is `False` by default

Comment: P.S. Is it normal to deprecate function with clear functionality for long code snippets with tons of potential bug sources?

Comment: Yes. The methods will be deprecated if there is a performance improvement.

Comment: To answer your previous query, if there is no document in the collection, then you will obviously be using insert_one which will insert the new document.

Comment: `if` will go to first branch, because there is an `_id` in doc

Comment: This is not an atomic operation.

Answer (score 2):

If you read a document and modify it, then replace the document on the server with the modified copy, then you should use `replace_one`:

```
doc = collection.find_one()
doc['key'] = value
collection.replace_one({'_id': doc['_id']}, doc)
```

If your intention is to update a particular field in the document, however, then `update_one` is faster (it requires one round-trip to the server instead of two) and safer (it is not prone to the same race conditions if multiple processes are updating the same document).

Comment: Did you mean that `collection.replace_one({'_id': doc['_id']}, doc)` is equivalent to `save`?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.

Comment: What if there is no document in the collection yet and also no `_id` in `doc` yet? Save was handling this automatically.

Comment: To insert the document if its not there set ```upsert``` optional parameter to true. See documentation @ https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/