# 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'save' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado

I am using tornado to build a simple website with mongoDB. I used python 3.7 and latest version of pymongo to control data in MongoDB but when I edit data in MongoDB with `save` methods as code below, the following error occurred:

> TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'save' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

```
    def post(self, isbn=None):
        import time
        book_fields = ['isbn', 'title', 'subtitle', 'image', 'author', 'date_released', 'description']
        burtbook = self.application.db.BurtBook
        book = dict()
        if isbn:
            book = burtbook.find_one({"isbn":isbn})
        for key in book_fields:
            book[key] = self.get_argument(key, None)

        if isbn:
            burtbook.save(book)
        else:
            book['add_released'] = int(time.time())
            burtbook.insert_one(book)
        self.redirect("/recommended/")
```

Please help me to fix this bug.

Comment: i actually experience the same. are you using flask-pymongo ? i actually found a workaround for this. i will post my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i dont know why, but i think there is a bug with `save` or its `deprecated` since end of 2020?

the savior method will be: `update_one($old_document, $keys_to_update)`

i saw on [this reference](https://www.w3schools.com/python/showpython.asp?filename=demo_mongodb_update_one) that you can update in place a `document` and keep the `ObjectID` unmodified (you will have the original document id)

your code will become (comments will explain everything)

```py
def post(self, isbn=None):
    import time
    book_fields = ['isbn', 'title', 'subtitle', 'image', 'author', 'date_released', 'description']
    burtbook = self.application.db.BurtBook
    book = dict()
    if isbn:
        book = burtbook.find_one({"isbn": isbn})
        # set is a specifier to mongo to update the values;
        # you just need to pass which value to modify on which key
        # example
        # keys_to_update = {"$set": { "bookName": "newNameSetByYou"}}
        # but the bookName key name remains the same
        keys_to_update = {"$set": {}}

    for key in book_fields:
        value = self.get_argument(key, None)
        book[key] = value
        if isbn:
            # here if isbn we create that dictionary to tell
            # mongo which value to modify on which key
            keys_to_update["$set"].update({
                key: value
            })
            # simple and old pythonic dict update

    if isbn:
        # here we update the document book with new values
        # from the above generated dict
        burtbook.update_one(book, keys_to_update)
        # just like the save()
        # save is deprecated boys, cant use it anymore ...
    else:
        book['add_released'] = int(time.time())
        burtbook.insert_one(book)
    self.redirect("/recommended/")
```

okey, on my defense, i couldnt test your code, but i've tested the same technique on my project and it know that it works for me.

just tell me if it works. pace

**EDIT**

another helpful [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866702/save-is-deprecated-for-what-in-pymongo)

and also you can try this code too (here you replace the entire document with whatever you want):

```py
todos_collection = get_collection(todos_collection_name)
requested_todo = todos_collection.find_one({
    "_id": ObjectId(oid)
})

todos_collection.replace_one(requested_todo, {"something": "else"})
# this will replace the entire document `request_todo` with `{"something": "else"}`
# but it will keep the original `ObjectID`
# and thats is very useful
```

Comment: I just used this modified code to:
```if isbn:
            burtbook.update_one({"isbn":isbn},{"$set":book})
        else:
            book['add_released'] = int(time.time())
            burtbook.insert_one(book)```
, and it worked. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: hold on: with this line `burtbook.update_one({"isbn":isbn},{"$set":book})` you actually  update an old `book` with your new `book` OR you just add a new `book` at document with `{"isbn":isbn}` ?

Comment: i updated old book because key isbn is old key of this book, so it just updates the state of book in DB